# jQuery fancyBox Closing icon

Tags: jquery, image, button, fancybox

I've installed Lightbox gallery on my html site. Photo's are opening perfect but, the closing icon isn't displaying correcly. What "falls off" the image isn't displayed. Did not change the code or lightbox css. The z-index is fine. Really don't know what te problem could be.

http://i39.tinypic.com/23jmo86.jpg

Comment: Could you post your code or a URL to your page? ... Just looking at your image doesn't give a way of identifying what's going on.

Comment: do you have any swf object behind fancybox on the main page? if so, set wmode to opaque of such object

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the use of overflow:hidden somewhere in your css. There's a simple solution for this. Add this to your css:

```
.fancybox-opened {overflow:visible !important;}
```

And it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you have:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Somewhere in your page CSS?  If so, you need to make the CSS selector more specific.

Setting the overflow to hidden on an example fancybox results in a div that looks exactly like that.  Not only is the close button cropped, but the drop shadow is cropped off too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/QuGme/

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/QuGme/1/

Other than that, it is difficult to say without seeing your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ive just noticed that theres an inline style of filter `alpha(opacity=100); WIDTH: 720px`

Which if i disable seems to show the close button correctly.