# jQuery fancyBox closing icon cropped in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I am experimenting with Fancybox to provide a modal login for a site hosted on the Wild Apricot online membership system.

Restyling remains to be done, but there is a major flaw in the way the box displays in IE8 (it's fine in FF, Chrome, & Opera). There should be an opaque circle with an X in the top-right corner of the box; in IE8 only the part of the circle that overlaps the box is visible - the rest is cropped.

An earlier question [jQuery fancyBox Closing icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217408/jquery-fancybox-closing-icon) produced one suggestion, (misapplied overflow:hidden) but changing the two instances I could find in the various CSS files made no difference.

The page is here: [www.eastmidlandsletb.net](http://www.eastmidlandsletb.net). To launch the box click on the link "Login & manage account" below the main menu.

I am assuming this is some IE CSS glitch, but it's beyond my knowledge level. How can I make it work in IE?

Comment: Simple solution: delete fancybox_sprite.png.

Answer (score 1):

Your page does not have a valid DOCTYPE.

Comment: Set by the CMS, over which I have no control. Is this a possible cause?